# UI Received task got cancelled

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

In my application, I am trying to update the user profile which calls the Rest API. API has one sync method UpdateProfile where execution getting stuck.

this line of code is ending the execution

```
command.UserProfile.LookupItems = GetLookupItemsByUserId(existingUser.Id).Result;
```

When i changed this line of code to

```
command.UserProfile.LookupItems = Task.Run(async () => await GetLookupItemsByUserId(existingUser.Id)).Result;
```

It started working without any issue.Can anybody explain to me what is going on behind the scene?

Answer (score 2):

The first version is blocking the current thread, when the task complete the blocked thread cannot catch it.

```
YourType Signature() {
    var neverUsedValue = task.Result;
}
```

The second one is yielding the current "thread" until the task is returned.

```
YourType Signature() {
    var value = Task.Run(await => async MethodThatWillComplete()).Result
}
```

What you should do is propagate the async to the method:

```
async Task<YourType> SignatureAsync() {
    command.UserProfile.LookupItems = await GetLookupItemsByUserId(existingUser.Id);
}
```

In this way you will avoid handling the `AggregateException`.

Comment: Since this method is used in so many places. I have not changed the method return type. instead used this code "command.UserProfile.LookupItems = Task.Run(async () => await GetLookupItemsByUserId(existingUser.Id)).Result;" which works for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is  very well written article on this here:[Don't block async](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)
In a few words, blocking on async code is bad because it may be blocking the thread which is supposed to run the async code and thus generete a deadlock.